# HTML bold in esc_html_e php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm editing a WordPress plugin to add a feature I want, and I want to make the variable `$time_of_post` bold in

```
<?php esc_html_e( "Schedule on $time_of_post", 'automatic-post-scheduler' ); ?>
```

The problem is that when I try to do:

```
<?php esc_html_e( "Schedule on <b> $time_of_post </b>", 'automatic-post-scheduler' ); ?>
```

It literally prints the tags:

```
<b> date here </b>
```

and doesn't apply it. I need it to be `esc_html_e` because when I tried using `echo`, it failed to run at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`esc_html` or `esc_html_e` do escape HTML spacial characters so you can't use this functions at all.

But `esc_html_e` is actually:

```
<?php
function esc_html_e( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
        echo esc_html( translate( $text, $domain ) );
}
```

So we can just use:

```
<?php
    echo translate( "Schedule on ", 'automatic-post-scheduler' );
    echo $time_of_post;
```